# Struts2: how to return result from action to some callback in the same jsp using $.post

Tags: java, jquery, struts2, callback

I send function from getMinimizedFunction.jsp using $.post to some struts2 action, which call some java method that clculates the minimized function. How can I return the minimized function from the action to the callback function in the same jsp getMinimizedFunction.jsp?

I have in my getMinimizedFunction.jsp the following code:

```
              String function="A*B'+A*B";
              url='getMinFunction.action';
              pars={function:function};
             $.post(url,pars,someCallback);


function someCallback(data){
     do something with data;  //data =A (the minimized Function)
    }
```

Comment: By returning either a string, JSON, etc? What are you really asking?

Comment: Er, no, I was telling you that you should return a string, or JSON, or something else. What are you really asking? Returning a string is as simple as putting the string into a JSP.

Comment: How to return this string to the same jsp getMinimizedFunction.jsp?

Comment: ... By having the action return a result like any other action. IMO use JSON, since there's a JSON plugin that serializes things automagically. Or use a JSP with a single `${minimizedFunction}` in it, where `minimizedFunction` is an action property holding a string. Or write directly to the request (but don't do that). Or... whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return stream result as explained [in this tutorial](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.11.1/docs/ajax.html)

```
<action name="getMinFunction" class="YourClass">
 <result type="stream">
    <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
    <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
  </result>
</action>
```

Or, you can use [struts2-jquery-plugin](http://www.weinfreund.de/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action) , it makes working with ajax simpler.